# Is there an algorithm which adaptively minimizes the number of comparisons between items?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose you want to sort a list based on human input of pairwise preferences (assume their preferences are transitive). Let's assume that computational cost doesn't matter, and all you care about is minimizing the number of queries to the user. What's the best you can do? (In terms of actual worst case or average case number of comparisons, not just asymptotically).

Is the best option to just run something like Timsort using the user inputs? It seems like you should be able to do some more intelligent selection of queries using your extra compute, but maybe not.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge-insertion_sort is not optimal, but is not far from it.

Comment: This is addressed at length in "The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 3 Sorting and Searching, D. E. Knuth". The exact number for arbitrary N is still unkonwn.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you want to post that (+ possibly an excerpt) as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: There is too much material. But these books are well known.